# Adding Arch Linux's repository to Manjaro

Tags: manjaro, pacman

Is it safe to use Archlinux's repository within Manjaro Linux installation?

If it is, all I need to do is just add some line to /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To build a package in Arch Linux not included in Manjaro use [`asp`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_Build_System#Retrieve_PKGBUILD_source_using_Git):

```
yaourt asp-https
sudo pacman -S base-devel
cp /etc/makepkg.conf ~/.makepkg.conf
mkdir ~/build/asp && cd ~/build/asp
```

- Adjust the values in `~/.makepkg.conf` &
- `asp checkout the-package-name`
- look for the `PKGBUILD` in either the `repo` or `trunk` subfolder
  of `the-package-name` & `cd` into it's location.
- finally run `makepkg`

I used this to build the `linux-hardened` kernel which is not in Manjaro & which also needed `xmlto` & `bc` as build dependencies.

I also subsequently rebuilt [manjaro-system](https://gitlab.manjaro.org/packages/core/manjaro-system) to **not** have a dependency on `linux>=3.1` so I can install the Arch Linux `hardened` & `lts` kernels with the [Archzfs modules](https://github.com/archzfs/archzfs) & not have to keep a manjaro kernel installed.

Comment: no longer use manjaro and arch, but i think this the acceptable answer :3

Answer (score 4):

From the [Manjaro wiki](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php?title=Manjaro:_A_Different_Kind_of_Beast):

> "Manjaro systems do not –and cannot– access the official Arch
>   repositories"

Though they don't mention a technical reason. Both distros use the Pacman package manager, though maybe the configuration settings or digital signatures are incompatible. Access to the AUR from Manjaro is possible.

I don't know about the [reverse case](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/285177/can-we-add-manjaro-repository-to-arch-linux/297871#297871).

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about Manjaro, but you shouldn't mess with standard repository, you could possibly ruin your system (i.e., the system libraries might just conflict).

I guess you just want to install some specific package, so use `abs` to retrieve it, and generate a package manually, then install it with `pacman -U XX.xz`

Answer (score 0):

Manjaro developers move Arch stuff in their repo very quick but a stable release in Arch may take about a week to be moved in to stable repo of Manjaro. The easy way is to move into the unstable branch. This directly ports packages from stable Arch repo.

`sudo pacman-mirrors --api --set-branch unstable`

`sudo pacman-mirrors --fasttrack 5 && sudo pacman -Syyu`

Comment: How is it possible in theory for this to work given the statement in jiggunjer's answer "Manjaro systems do not –and cannot– access the official Arch repositories"?

Comment: firstly it do not change the repository to Arch, it uses a different Manjaro repository which is more nearer to Arch along the supply chain.

Comment: Secondly, you can  add, but it is not recommended and dangerous. Since they have competing system package they may break your system and neither of the distro support doing so. But you can always accept the risk and continue. But if you do, you better do it once and move to Arch otherwise you may face trouble time to time over shared libs.