# Can we add Manjaro repository to Arch-Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, pacman, manjaro

Can we add a Manjaro repository to Arch-Linux, or is it different from how arch-repos work? If so, how can we do it?

Comment: You may be able to add them to your ``pacman.conf`` like you can with other non-official repositories. Though, I would wonder why you would want to do this.

Comment: how? one example is to use an older kernel, linux 4.19 is crashing with amdgpu, linux 4.18 isn't, and manjaro keep old kernels' packages

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, you can, you can set the repositories in pacman.conf and your mirrorlist, so if you were to make your arch linux pacman.conf look like the [pacman.conf on a manjaro installation](https://github.com/manjaro/packages-core/blob/master/pacman/pacman.conf.x86_64), and do similar changes for the [mirrorlist](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php/Change_to_a_Different_Download_Server#Editing_the_mirrorlist) (needs to point to a manjaro mirror), pacman commands would seek packages from the manjaro repositories. (there may be a few extra steps, like installing the manjaro keyring for example)

Whether or not it's a good idea on the other hand... Well, it's not, it's a horrible idea, don't do it. Just use manjaro if you want manjaro repos. I don't see any reason why you'd be better off doing it any other way. Something's gonna break if you do this. A lot of somethings, probably.

Even if you were to successfully do this, at the end of the day you would, after you get everything working, end up with manjaro, not arch.

If you wanna install some manjaro package, you don't have to go through all this trouble at all, you can just download the pkg file and install it with **pacman -U** to see if it works.

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible without issues to use Arch repositories under Manjaro, so it might be a bad idea to do the opposite. From the Manjaro Wiki:

> Although Manjaro is one-hundred percent Arch Linux compatible —being based on Arch Linux itself— it is not possible to access their official repositories for use in Manjaro.

- https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=213165
- https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php/Arch_User_Repository

Comment: I think OP would like to do the other way around, use Manjaro repos on a Arch installation

Comment: @DavidCosta yes, that's why "so it might be a bad idea to do the opposite" xD. Also, Manjaro had a bit older versions of the Arch packages, they took a while to bring latest releases (not sure what's the current status), better might be to just use the AUR.